# PayPal - Reserve/Freeze money

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am working on a WebService that will accept payments from PayPal. There will be two sides (seller and buyer) and I will take commissions. However, I don't want to direct the payment instantly to the seller. The seller will complete the service through some conversations, but I want to guarantee to the buyer that it will receive the service as he wants and at the same time, guarantee the seller that he will receive his money.

Is there a way to reserve/freeze/hold the money from the buyer's PayPal account or do I need to take all the service money instantly to my account and then direct the money afterwards, after taking my commission, when the service is marked as completed by both parties? What is the optimal way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delayed chained payment using Adaptive payment API would be the optimal way for your business pattern. It allows you to keep the money for 90 days during which you can pay the sellers their portion any time. You can refer to this page https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/#id091QF0I30YK to understand the basic function, and see this guide https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/ for implementation.